# Manage base theme with version control?

Tags: theme-development, version-control

I develop wordpress theme based on a base theme.
sometimes when i'm coding i want to add functions, or simply piece of code i've just added to to the theme i am working to my base theme.

in this way i can update my base theme and then update all other sites depending on it.

all my themes, even the base one is on my local computer.
i was thinking about to some version control. what do you think?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps write your custom themes as a [child of the base theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), then set up a [self-hosted theme update](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2011/06/02/automatic-updates-for-commercial-themes/).

Whenever you make changes to your base theme, push it to your update server with whichever version control you opt for (SVN, Git etc.), and it'll become available as a "regular" update to all your sites using the theme.

Throw in a service like [WPRemote](http://wpremote.com) or [InfiniteWP](http://infinitewp.com/) (self-hosted), and syncing the update with *all* of your sites is as easy as hitting a button!